# Simple summation algebra question: summation of a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

What does $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$$ yield?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The index on both sums can't be the same.

Comment: Why not? What rule is this violating?

Comment: If inner sum is $S$ then final sum is $nS$.

Comment: You mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} = n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=n^{2}x_{i}$, @cosmo5?

Comment: I mean  $n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$ It can't be simplified to $n^{2}x_{i}$ since $x_i$ is variable.

Comment: It simplifies to $n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$.  The inner sum is dependent on index $i$ but the outer sum is not.

Comment: Why is the outer sum not dependent on $i$, @CogitoErgoCogitoSum, isn't that a condition being imposed?

Comment: This is the answer, @cosmo5, and you were the first. If you want to answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Thanks @Zweifler. I wrote a brief answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let inner sum be $S$ i.e.,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = S$$

Now this is a constant. Hence

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\Big) =\sum_{i=1}^n S = nS$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem with $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is that the $i$ in $x_i$ could refer to the index of the inner sum or the index of the outer sum. In this case, it wouldn't matter since both have the same range, but more generally $\sum_{i=a}^b\sum_{i=c}^d x_i$ would have the problem of not knowing if $i$ should vary from $a$ to $b$ or from $c$ to $d$. That's why you'll never see such thing in a good book or a serious paper.

If you are interested in knowing what "rule" it violates read about [well-formed formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) and [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

Comment: What if $c=a$ and $b=d$, which is what I am looking at? Would the problem persist?

Comment: One could force an interpretation, but do you think is a good idea to use a notation that, in order to make sense, the variables need to satisfy certain conditions?